# Can i use this Barcode library on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, porting

Greeting,
can i use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeImaging3.aspx) library in Windows Phone 7?

There exists C# or VB.NET version.

Here is used namspaces:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections;
```

Or how can i know that I can use the library or I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without changes - `System.Drawing` isn't available in WP7 (or Silverlight in general, for that matter).

The simplest way to find out though is to create a new WP7 class library project, try to add the existing source to it, and then try to add the assemblies that the original code references.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to port libraries that are'nt developed exactly for WP7? I mean general alogrithm (mathematical, financial, ...) that are coded etc. in C++?

Comment: @Karlvonbahnhof: No, C++ isn't supported on WP7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a barcode scanning library in Silverlight or Windows Phone 7 you can check out the Silverlight ZXing port at http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/. The project includes sample code for using the library as well as a BarcodePhotoChooser XAML/CS page for displaying and choosing sample barcodes since the emulator does not support the camera. I created it for use in the [PhraseMeme Scanner](http://PhraseMeme.com/Scanner) app that was recently released to the marketplace, but I plan on submitting bug fixes and additional code to the project so that others can also use it in their Windows Phone 7 or Silverlight applications.